# Passing a method as an argument in self

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am currently learning about data structures. I have defined my own class and I am wanting to pass a method from within the class to another method inside the class. The methods that I have attempted to perform this do not seem to be working.

This is the code I have currently:

```
class BinaryTree
  attr_accessor :left_child, :right_child, :node
  def initialize(node, left_child, right_child)
    @left_child = left_child
    @right_child = right_child
    @node = node
  end

  def to_s
    "node: #{@node}, left: #{@left_child}, right: #{@right_child}"
  end

  def self.print_node
    p @node
  end

  def traverse(some_func)
    if !left_child.nil?
        left_child.traverse(some_func)
    end
    if !right_child.nil?
        right_child.traverse(some_func)
    end
    self.some_func
  end
end

bst = BinaryTree.new(50, 
      BinaryTree.new(30, BinaryTree.new(5, nil, nil), BinaryTree.new(20, nil, nil)),
      BinaryTree.new(60, BinaryTree.new(45, nil, nil), BinaryTree.new(70, BinaryTree.new(65, nil, nil), BinaryTree.new(80, nil, nil))) )


puts bst.traverse(bst.print_node)
```

Essentially I am wanting to traverse a binary tree and call some function on every child node. In this instance I am simply wanting to pass a function to print the node, however, this code is resulting in the following error.

```
 `<main>': undefined method `print_node' for #<BinaryTree:0x00007f82f88530b8> (NoMethodError)
```

I am hoping someone can shed some light on why this is failing and what I should look at doing instead to accomplish this.

Comment: When you're writing `self.some_method` you're defining a class method and when you're defining a method without `self` you're defining an instance method. `bst` is an instance object of `BinaryTree` and only has access to the instance methods defined. I won't comment on the code but removing the `self` should be sufficient to call print_node as you are attempting to access it.

Comment: remove `self` in `def self.print_node`

Comment: Thank you. That did help access the root node, however, it is still not calling the method within the traverse method. I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, but in the call bst.traverse(bst.print_node) it is calling that function and printing the root node, but everything after is not being called. What would be the proper way to call the method from within traverse? The call self.some_func seems to be referencing the class of the data rather than the class of the BinaryTree object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wanting to pass a method from within the class to another method inside the class

While you can do it that way, in Ruby this is done with [blocks](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument).

```
bst.traverse { |node|
  p node
}
```

What looks like loops and blocks in Ruby are actually little anonymous functions called [Procs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html). Here's the above with the syntax sugar stripped away.

```
block = Proc.new { |node| p node }
bst.traverse(&block)
```

The `&` says the argument is to be treated as a block.

And you'd write `traverse` to take a block like so:

```
  def traverse(&block)
    if !left_child.nil?
      left_child.traverse(&block)
    end
    if !right_child.nil?
      right_child.traverse(&block)
    end
    
    block.call(@node)
  end
```

Same thing, [`&` says to treat the argument as a block](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument). And we pass the block along recursively. `block` is a Proc object, we call it with [`#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-call), and pass in whatever arguments we like.

You'll also see people use [`yield`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Block+Argument). This does basically the same thing, but without having to explicitly define `&block`. For now, do it explicitly until you're comfortable. In this case we must do it explicitly because we're passing the block along recursively.

---

Procs act like normal functions with two key differences:

1. `return` does not return from the Proc, it returns from the surrounding method.
2. It does not check required arguments.

Lambdas work more like normal functions with arguments checked and `return` returning. You can learn more in [Lambda and non-lambda semantics](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Lambda+and+non-lambda+semantics).

---

See [Blocks: What Are They Good For?](https://thoughtbot.com/upcase/videos/blocks-what-are-they-good-for) for more.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "pass a method to another method" in quite the same way as some other languages such as Javascript. It *is* possible, using [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-method) or passing a symbol to [`Object#send`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send), but it's more typically done using an *anonymous function* like so:

```
  # Note I removed the `self.` here
  def print_node
    p @node
  end

  def traverse(&block)
    if !left_child.nil?
      left_child.traverse(&block)
    end
    if !right_child.nil?
      right_child.traverse(&block)
    end
    block.call(self)
  end
```

And you'd call it like:

```
 bst.traverse { |tree| tree.print_node }
```

You could also shorten that to:

```
  bst.traverse(&:print_node)
```

I would recommend reading up on anonymous functions in Ruby. It's a little too much to cover here but there are a lot of good resources about it

Comment: Might be better written as `bst.traverse { |tree| tree.print_node }`, since it's the tree being passed in. Or don't pass an argument: `bst.traverse { bst.print_node }`. Really node should be its own class.

Comment: That's a good point, the `node` variable would be better called `tree`. But your second example wouldn't work - the tree referred to in the block is not necessarily the toplevel tree.